# How can I build a React app with Webpack and import an assets folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, assets

My main problem is that I'm trying to build a React Application but the assets folder is missing and I don't know how to import it and configure it in webpack.conf. Another problem is the relative route of index.html: I don't know if it will be affected in the application build.

Thanks in advance.

[Application Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sKsA.png)

[image]

***index.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="src/assets/favicon.ico"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

***Webpack Config:***

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
      },
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin("style.css")
  ],
  // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [webpack-copy-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy additional folders / files as part of the build process

```
new CopyPlugin([{ 
  from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'assets'), 
  to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'assets') 
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

As @James mentioned: "*You can use [webpack-copy-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy additional folders / files as part of the build process*"

However, there is a small error while using you example @James, it should be like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
  plugins: [
    //...
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'assets'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'assets') },
      ],
    })
  ],
```

Hope it helps (upvote james for his help if it helps you too)